# Table.ListRows.Add works properly on my computer but none of the other computers in our 20 computer chem lab

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully this makes sense. I created a macro that will read off information from a master sheet, create worksheets based off the name of an analyte, and then after the worksheet is created, it will transfer 8 cells of information from the master sheet to a table on the newly created analyte sheet.

On my computer, when I run the my code using a step-into, when the line Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add is run, a new line is created and the 6 rows of the table are already filled in with whatever information was found on the first row of the table, then that data gets overwritten as the With portion of the set statement gets run.

On every other computer, when I run my code using a step-into, when the line Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add is run, a new line is created and the 6 rows of the table are already filled in with whatever information was found on the first row of the table, then ALL data gets overwritten as the with portion of the set statement gets run. For instance, is there are 3 entries in my table, as the with statement is run for the 3rd entry, all entries on that row get overwritten at the same time.

When running on my computer, all entries are different like they are supposed to be. On all other computers, all entries resemble the final entry to the table which is not supposed to happen. The excel file is stored in a network area and everyone accessed the same file. The file contains no external references(Activeworkbook only).

Hoping that someone can help as I am beyond confused why this is happening.

1) I have tried to make sure the excel version and windows version is identical to the one the code was created on(did not work)

```
For Each Cell In AnalyteName
    If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 35 Then
        WorkSheetName = Cell.Value
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If WorkSheetName = ws.Name Then
                Set Table = ws.ListObjects(WorkSheetName)
                Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add
                    With NewAnalyte
                        .Range(1) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, -1).Address
                        .Range(2) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 1).Address
                        .Range(3) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 2).Address
                        .Range(4) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
                        .Range(5) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 4).Address
                        .Range(6) = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 5).Address
                    End With
                Range(Cell.Offset(0, -2), Cell.Offset(0, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            End If
        Next ws
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Does your sheet name "Standard List " really have space at the end?

Comment: What you see on other computers is default - automatic change of all formulas in a Table column, but it can be disabled as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40697914)

Comment: @BrakNicku That was exactly the problem and your solution worked fantastic. Is there anyway to give you props for that answer? I'm new to StackOverFlow

Comment: I just linked the solution. You can _give props_ to the author of the linked answer by upvoting it, but to be able to do that, I think you need to have 15 reputation points first.

Answer (score 1):

Try being a little more explicit when setting the formulas:

```
With NewAnalyte.Range
   .Cells(1).Formula = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, -1).Address
   .Cells(2).Formula = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 1).Address
   .Cells(3).Formula = = "='Standard List '!" + Cell.Offset(0, 2).Address
   'etc      
End With
```

Comment: I will try to be more explicit when setting formulas in the future but in this case, it didn't change anyways. Still is great advice though as I learn to code in VBA. BrakNicku's comment above fixed the problem I was having in this case