# Excel VBA Module is inserting formula in entire column rather than single cell in row

Tags: excel, vba, module

I've looked through these forums extensively but haven't found a working solution to the strange issue I'm having.

Currently I have a spreadsheet where when a cell in column W is double clicked, a vba module is called to insert a string of text in column P of the same row that was clicked. This works with the following module:

```
Sub CommentPrinted()
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value = "NL at Nurses Station"
End Sub
```

This worked as intended but now I want to change this module slightly to insert that text string as well as the current day and month in brackets. In attempting to do so I changed the module to:

```
Sub CommentPrinted()
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Formula = "=""NL at Nurses Station (""&DAY(TODAY())&""/""&MONTH(TODAY())&"")"""
End Sub
```

Although this does insert "NL at Nurses Station (day/month)" into column P as desired, rather than being inserted into a single cell, it is inserted into every row of my table in column P, overwriting any existing values.

Any suggestions as to how I can make sure the module only acts on column P of the row selected like the module did originally?

ADDITIONAL INFO
Strangely if I run the module a second time after it has inserted the value in all cells in column P, it works perfectly?

Comment: Is this inserting into an excel table?  are there any other update events on the sheet?  Does it happen if you build the string value without the formula?

Comment: `it is inserted into every row of** my table ** in column P` You may want to see [How do I prevent Excel from automatically replicating formulas in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697706/how-do-i-prevent-excel-from-automatically-replicating-formulas-in-tables)

Comment: If it's a table then `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` before adding the formula.  Think that's the VBA version of bzimors answer in @SiddharthRout link.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why your entire column gets filled, the statement itself runs for the Activecell, and that can only be one cell at a time. Maybe you have a problem with cascading events, set a breakpoint to the routine and check with the debugger from where (and how often) it is called: View->Call Stack (Ctrl+L)

However, following remark: You shouldn't use a formula to add the date. A formula is recalculated whenever Excel thinks is should. If you open your file tomorrow, it will no longer display today's date but tomorrows. Instead, write the current date into the cell as a fixed string:

```
value = "NL at Nurses Station " & format(now, "dd/mm")
```

Comment: Well modifying the module with your suggestion as:
```ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value = "NL at Nurses Station (" & Format(Now, "dd/mm") & ")"```
Seemed to do the trick - it's now working perfectly!
Still not sure on how or why but thank you kindly!